# Pytorch nn.Parameter only updates for first epoch

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to implement a custom Module (this is simplified version), and my inspecting the variable `self.param` during each iteration the value doesn't change after the first iteration even though the gradient has a value. Does anyone familiar with pytorch have any idea why this is happening?

```
class Custom_RNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Custom_RNN, self).__init__()
        self.hl1 = nn.Linear(2, 1024)
        self.hl2 = nn.Linear(1024, 512)
        self.out = nn.Linear(512, 1)
        self.param = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor([250]), requires_grad=True)

    def forward(self, state_init, input, output):

        combined = torch.cat((state_init, input[0]), 1)
        out = torch.sigmoid(self.hl1(combined))
        out = torch.sigmoid(self.hl2(out))
        out = self.out(out)

        for t in range(input.shape[1]):

            # Predict SoC
            shifted_out = out + input[t]/self.param

            combined = torch.cat((shifted_out, input[t]), 1)
            out = torch.sigmoid(self.hl1(combined))
            out = torch.sigmoid(self.hl2(out))
            out = self.out(out)
            if first:
                loss = torch.pow(out - output[t], 2.0)
            else:
                loss = loss + torch.pow(out - output[t], 2.0)

        return loss

rnn = Custom_RNN()
optimiser = optim.Adam(rnn.parameters())

for epoch in range(epochs):
    optimiser.zero_grad()
    loss = rnn(initial_cond, data_in, data_out)
    rnn_param_before = rnn.param.item()
    loss.backward()
    optimiser.step()
    rnn_param_after = rnn.param.item()
    print(rnn_param_before - rnn_param_after)
    print(rnn.param.item(), rnn.param.grad)
```

The first epoch the first print gets a number that is not zeros, then every other epoch it is 0.0 and the second print statement shows that the value remains the same and the grad is non zero always.

Comment: Is this an actual code? There is a copy-paste error `super(RNNetwork, self)`.

Comment: No its not the actual code it has been significantly cut down the original is quite big. Thanks for pointing out the example mistake